# SetViewBox moving the paper

Tags: raphael

I am using the setViewBox() function in Raphael 2. The width and height is multiplied by a value like (1.2, 1.3 ...). This changes the magnification/ zooming properly but the x and y which I have given as 0,0 makes the paper display its contents after some offset. If i modify the x and y to some positive value after the rendering( using firebug!!) then the top left of the paper moves back and above to its right position. I want to know how will the value be calculated. I have no idea about how the x,y affect the viewbox. If anybody can give me any pointers for this it will be a real help.

I have tried giving the difference between the width/ height divided by 2. Also I must mention that I am not rendering an image but various raphael shapes e.g. rects, paths text etc. in my paper.

Looking forward to some help!
Kavita

Answer (score 1):

this is an example showing how to calculate the setViewBox values, I included jquery (to get my SVG cocntainer X and Y : $("#"+map_name).offset().left and $("#"+map_name).offset().top) and after that I calculated how much zoom I need :

```
var original_width = 777;
var original_height = 667;
var zoom_width = map_width*100/original_width/100;
var zoom_height = map_height*100/original_height/100;
if(zoom_width<=zoom_height)
   zoom = zoom_width;
else
   zoom = zoom_height;
rsr.setViewBox($("#"+map_name).offset().left, $("#"+map_name).offset().top, (map_width/zoom), (map_height/zoom));
```

Answer (score 0):

did you put the center of your scaling to 0,0 like:

```
element.scale(1.2,1.2,0,0);
```

this can scale your element without moving the coordinates of the top left corner.

Comment: Sorry I have resolved the issue... I put 0,0 in the x,y values and what looked like the paper shifting is actually the objects in the paper getting enlarged so the corner part appeared to become bigger.Sorry for the late update! Thanks all for your inputs!